# Simple recurrence relation - 1D

Tags: recurrence-relations

I know this is a very simple recurrence relation, but how would you go on solving it?

$$x(n+1)=\frac{x(n)}{1+x(n)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $y(n)=\frac{1}{x(n)}$. The recurrence for $y(n)$ is **very** pleasantly simple.